# Why my setViewFromArray resulting same position?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to get the camera position and camera target using `viewer.getViewArrayFromCamera()` but every time I run the value with function below, the camera path is always in the center of the building. (resulting in the same position).

```
startCameraTransition() {
    this.viewer.autocam.shotParams.destinationPercent = 3;
    this.viewer.autocam.shotParams.duration = 7;
    this.viewer.impl.toggleProgressive(false);
    this.viewer.setViewFromArray([
      -1.9418035665709943, -26.747346936530814, 18.603221077622162,
      -1.9403051859659226, -24.92825998040271, 17.619854897824176, 0, 0, 1,
      1.171960569550931, 0.761012, 0.02539999969303608, 0,
    ]);
    this.viewer.impl.renderer().setAOOptions(4, 0.8);
  }
```

Comment: sorry for our late response. I tried with a simple model. call getViewArrayFromCamera() to get data of current view, and navigate the model to other view point, then call setViewFromArray with the data above, the view can restored to previous one. Is there anything I missed to reproduce the problem at your side?

Comment: In addition, could you help me understand  what does it mean by [camera path] and [same position]? Any snapshots would be much helpful. You could also email to forge.help [AT] autodesk.com if you do not want to post snapshots in public.